# Copiar los datos de un row a otro en un DatagridView en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hola estoy intentando hacer que mi datagridview pueda copiar la informacion de una celda a otra pero cuando lo intento la celda me aparece en blanco como lo pueden ver en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacer esto para ver si me funciona

```
        Dim Test As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Test.Name = "Test"
        Test.HeaderText = "Code"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, Test)

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows


            row.Cells("2").Value = row.Cells(1).Value

        Next
```

Pero aun asi no me ha funcionado.

Muchas por la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer

Comment: Ese código en que evento o función está?? Además quieres que `P0001` aparezca en la celda del lado donde dice `code`?

Comment: Las celdas cuentan de 0 para adelante, por lo tanto, ahora estas intentando asignar a una celda llamada "2" el valor de la celda 1, lo que significa que intentas asignar a una celda inexistente un valor vacio ya que la celda 1 no tiene valor en ninguno de los casos. Creo que con `row.Cells(1).Value = row.Cells(0).Value' debería funcionar

Comment: @Yussef si eso es para hacer un prueba mas adelante con otro codigo

Comment: @Marc Si ya lo cambie el orden pero aun asi todavia me aparece la celda en blanco